# How can I encode a urllib item

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup, urllib

I've read an answer on how you have to `.encode("utf-8")` to render other languages but, I'm not sure where to put it in this code:

```py
a = urlopen(url).encode("utf-8")
soup_obj = soup(a,"html.parser")
print(soup_obj.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

After read, the code is as follows.

```
a = urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
soup_obj = soup(a,"html.parser")
```

Two more ways are recommended. You don't need to worry about languages.

```
import requests
a = requests.get(url).text

from simplified_scrapy.request import req
a = req.get(url)
```